# Help with updating and archiving data

Tags: mysql, php, snapshot, archive

I'm building a MySQL database and a frontend.  One function of the database application is to make an invoice.  I'm looking for a way to archive all of the data that went onto the invoice so that if some data changes, the invoiced data is still available.

For example:
On table `customers`,

```
|---------+-------------------+-------------|
|  name   | email             | phone       |
|---------+-------------------+-------------|
|  George | george@domain.com | 3179094235  |
|---------+-------------------+-------------|
```

Suppose I make an invoice for George in year 2017.  In 2018, George changes his phone number.  I want my database to have a current phone number for George.  Now in 2018, my `customers` table looks like

```
|---------+-------------------+-------------|
|  name   | email             | phone       |
|---------+-------------------+-------------|
|  George | george@domain.com | 2024123987  |
|---------+-------------------+-------------|
```

but I want the data that my invoice used to still be used in 2018 when I generate the invoice document again.

In the real world, much more data will be put onto the invoice.  How can I make it so that the invoice that I generate in 2017 will use all of the same data as the one I generated in 2018, even if I've updated the data in my database?  Invoice is currently generated from data from multiple tables: parts, labor, customer info, etc. Can I archive all of the invoice data to a table, and always generate invoices from the archive table? Snapshots? Transactions?  I'm new to databases, so I don't know if I'm looking for a MySQL feature or a database design technique, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You have two things.  You need two tables to handle such.

- A record of Invoices.  Once an invoice is issued, the row(s) that describe must not be modified.  There can be many rows for George, assuming he is issued many invoices.
- *Current* information about George, etc.  This is updated as needed; there is one row for George.

It may be that, when issuing a new Invoice, you need to reach into the other table to update that info.  So, simply plan on always issuing two statements, preferably in the same transaction:

```
INSERT INTO Invoices ...;
UPDATE Current ...;   -- No harm if nothing actually changes.
```